# trying to display shimmer effect while angular bootstaping, but the animation gets stuck

Tags: angular

Im trying to display facebook's shimmer affect while bootstraping angular (first load), but the animation gets stuck/stop after a second +- 
The code cannot contain angular code, only css & html & js because it is running before angular.

Im using this css & html-

```
.shine {
  background: #f6f7f8;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6f7f8 0%, #edeef1 20%, #f6f7f8 40%, #f6f7f8 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 800px 104px; 
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; 

  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: placeholderShimmer;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

box {
  height: 104px;
  width: 100px;
}

keyframes placeholderShimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -468px 0;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 468px 0; 
  }
}
```

Html :

```
<ngx-application>
   <div class="box shine"></div>
</ngx-appliaction>
```

I think the problem is with animating background-position. When I tried to animate other property (translate, scale, roatete and more) the animation worked perfectly. The element with scale kept scaling up and down but the element with background-position animated got stuck. if I combine animating scale and background-position on the same element it gets stuck aswell.

In addition, when I run the animation after angular's bootstraping, on just a random component, the animation works infinitly. I tried searching on the web but I remained clueless.
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Run the animation in Angular, after your initial BootStrap, but change the CSS file or make your own `"shine"` class but change:

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

To

```
animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

This will stop it running infinitely as it seems this is not the desired behavior according to your post. Additionally, you don't actually have to recreate the whole class if you don't want to, just override this specific property.

Comment: I want the iteration-count to be infinite, and I want it to run before angular is loaded, the problem is that this is not running infinite amount of time, it is running 1 second +- and then stops, I want it to keep running until angular loads.

Comment: @רתם שורץ Are you sure it isn't stopping, BECAUSE Angular is loading?

Comment: yes, I tried to animate it two boxes, one with background-position animated, and the second with scale animated. the scaling box kept geting bigger and smaller but te background-position box animation stops animating.